# how to use BitmapFactory.decodeFile() to get the Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-image, android-bitmap

i am trying to download image from internet in original quality. then trying to BitmapFactory.decodeFile() to get the Bitmap

to perform this task i tried this but i am getting this error:

`The method decodeFile(String) in the type BitmapFactory is not applicable for the arguments (FileOutputStream)`

code:

```
public void saveImageToSDCard(Bitmap bitmap) {
        String dirname = "/Amazing Wallpapers/";

        File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getPath() + dirname);

        myDir.mkdirs();     
        String str = currentUrl.substring(currentUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1,
                currentUrl.length());

        String fname = "Wallpaper-" + str + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            Toast.makeText(
                    _context,
                    _context.getString(R.string.toast_saved).replace("#",
                            "\"" + pref.getGalleryName() + "\""),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "Wallpaper saved to:" + file.getAbsolutePath());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(_context,
                    _context.getString(R.string.toast_saved_failed),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the file name to the function `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()`instead of the output stream